# remote queue manager alias not working as expected

Tags: ibm-mq

I have setup MQ7.0 On three system: A, B and C. A -> B there is sender-receiver channel (A.B) and B->C, there is sender-receiver channel(B.C). Transmission queue names are same.Name of queue managers as QMA,QMB and QMC respectively.
Now I have a queue QC on system C.
I have defined a remote queue definition on system A as:
define qremote(RQ) rname(QC) rqmname(third) xmitq(A.B)

I have a define remote queue mgr definition on system B as:
define qremote(third) rname('') rqmname(QMC) xmitq(B.C)

now what I expected when I put a message to remote queue RQ on A, it should travel to system B with transmission header "QC on third" through channel on tx queue(A.B)..on system B since third is aliased as QMC so this message should be put to tx B.C and should reach Queue QC on system C.
But after I put message, it is lost. Is my understanding wrong about remote queue mgr alias. Can someone give better example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**On QMA**

```
DEF QR(QMC) RQMNAME(' ')   RNAME(' ') XMITQ(QMB)
DEF QR(QC)  RQMNAME('QMC') RNAME(' ') XMITQ('QMB')
DEF QL(QMB) USAGE(XMITQ) TRIGTYPE(FIRST) TRIGGER
* Channel def goes here
```

The QRemote is a QMgr alias.  It specifies the path to QMC goes through the QMB XMitQ.  Once this is defined, anything destined for QMC will resolve to the QMB XMitQ.  The blank `RNAME` and `RQMNAME` is what makes this a QMgr alias and not a classic remote queue definition.  At this point if you use a tool like the Q program which allows you to specify the QMgr to connect to separately from the QMgr used for the `OPEN` command, you don't even need a `QRemote`.  ANY mesage destined for QMC will now resolve to QMB.

However, if you wanted to use something less sophisticated like `amqsput` then you really do need a QRemote.  The `DEF QR(QC` accomplishes this.  If you are willing to use QRemotes then you don't really need the QMgr alias.  This just says "If someone opens a queue named `QC` then address it to `QC` on `QMC` and put it on the `QMB` XMitQ.

**On QMB**

```
DEF QL(QMC) USAGE(XMITQ) TRIGTYPE(FIRST) TRIGGER
* Channel def goes here
```

On QMB when the mssages arrive addressed to QMC, they will automatically resolve to the XMitQ without any further definitions or guidance.

**On QMC**

```
DEF QL(QC)
```

Finally, the messages arrive on QMC addressed to QC so you need a QLocal for them to land in.

Name resolution is a bit complicated but once you understand it, you pretty much understand WMQ addressing.  I'd recommend sitting down with the [Name Resolution Infocenter topic](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fg12170_.htm) and reconciling back to the behavior you are seeing.

By the way, the discrepancy in your definitions appears to be that your QRemote used the name of the channel instead of the XMitQ.  At one point you say "Transmission queue names are same.Name of queue managers as QMA,QMB and QMC respectively."  So I expect on B to find an XMitQ named `QMC` serving the QMB.QMC channel.  But later you define the QMgr alias as `define qremote(third) rname('') rqmname(QMC) xmitq(B.C)` which should be `XMITQ(QMC)`.

Comment: Thanks. Your detailed response always provide more information. However I still have following queries: 1. On QMB, you specified to configure xmitq. I guess it is example of pass thru. On link :- http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzae.doc/ic10860_.htm , I was trying to perform second option which is using qmgr alias to change the message flow path. That is reason I have defined qmgr alias on system B: as define qremote(third) rname('') rqmname(QMC) xmitq(B.C) Pass thru is working in my setup but not this option.

Comment: Secondly, I am sorry I was not clear but I named but my transmission queue same as channel names like A.B, B.C. So not sure if you still see any issue with my current configuration.

Comment: Thirdly, I wish to know what is technical difference between QR(QMC) and QR(QC) you mentioned above. In QR(QC) def, you have XMITQ as blank. Is it typo? Also, about your statement "the Q program which allows you to specify the QMgr to connect to separately from the QMgr used for the OPEN command, you don't even need a QRemote". I have downloaded this support pac but unable to do what you mentioned. Please help.

Comment: Whoops! Good catch. As written, `DEF QR(QMC)` doesn't list an XMitQ and therefore *does* require the preceding QMgr alias. Had I specified the XMitQ it would stand alone.  I'll update that for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: Based on your follow-up explanation about the XMitQ name, to determine what's happening I need to know what 'lost' means. I'd expect the message to go to the DLQ ordinarily.  If there is no DLQ and the message is non-persistent then WMQ will discard it. First thing to do is make sure QMB and QMC both have a DLQ defined and that the QMgr's DEADQ attribute points to it. then look to see which DLQ the message goes into.  You can also make the message persistent but without a DLQ it just makes the channel go to retry which isn't as helpful.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I got to understand configuration issue after specifying DLQ. I could see if was failing with a message in DLQ with cause MQRC_UNKNOWN_REMOTE_Q_MGR. For everyone benefit, queue manager name is case-sensitive. My message was failing as it try to find THIRDQM but instead the real name of QM is ThirdQM. Thanks Rob again for your continuous help.

Comment: Ah, case sensitivity. I've been doing this for so long sometimes I forget to ask about the basics. Yeah, if you pass a string value to runmqsc it folds everything to upper case unless it is quoted. Glad you got it sorted out!

Comment: @T.Rob Based on the example you provided **On QMA** `DEF QR(QC)  RQMNAME('QMC') RNAME(' ') XMITQ('QMC')` should be `DEF QR(QC)  RQMNAME('QMC') RNAME(' ') XMITQ('QMB')`, I ca not make this edit however since it is only a one character difference.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc, I fixed it.